# Link XSD-File in WADL

Tags: rest, xsd, cxf, jax-rs, wadl

I would like to create a WADL-File from which Java Interfaces can be created using Apache CXF `wadl2java` Maven plugin. 
In the WADL I would like to use the Datatypes defined in a XSD-File.

These are my REST Services:

```
@Path("/v1/order")
public interface OrderResource {

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response createOrder(Order order);

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Order> getOrders(@QueryParam("orderId") List<Long> orderIds);
}
```

My WADL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" >
    <grammars>
        <include href="RestService_schema1.xsd" />
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://localhost:9080/rest/">
        <resource path="v1/order/" id="OrderResource">
            <resource>
                <method name="PUT" id="createOrder">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml"  />
                    </request>
                    <response status="200">
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
            <resource>
                <method name="GET" id="getOrders">
                    <request>
                        <param name="orderId" style="query" type="xs:long" />
                    </request>
                    <response status="200">
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml" />
                    </response>
                </method>
        </resource>   
    </resources>
</application>
```

My RestService_schema1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Order" type="Order" />
    <xs:complexType name="Order">
        <xs:attribute name="OrderId" type="orderid">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:sequence>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="orderid">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> ....
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**What I want to do:**

- I would like to specify in my WADL the input type Order for the createOrder Service. I know this can be done with the element-attribute, but how can I link it? Maybe `element="Order"` within the `<representation>`-Tag??
- The Query Param of the getOrders()-Service should be `List<Long>` (in the WADL a List with orderid's) and the Response Type `List<Order>`. How can I specify this in the WADL?